# How to persist Cognito User Session

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I am using javascript sdk for AWS cognito and able to login with aws cognito and receiving tokens in response.

I can see that the user session is valid until I refresh the page. Please suggest how the user session can persist after refreshing the page.

Below is my code.

```
function getSession() {
let poolData = {
    UserPoolId: _config.cognito.userPoolId, // Your user pool id here
    ClientId: _config.cognito.clientId, // Your client id here
};

//alert(sessionStorage.getItem("SessionName"));


let userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());
    //Set the profile info
    cognitoUser.getUserAttributes(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("------>>" + result);
        //document.getElementById("email_value").innerHTML = result[2].getValue();  
    });

});
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

good news - the SDK does this for you. [Check out their code for the `getsession` method](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/81cbfd4d89c1f9fbf53691d1287f9639c9fe7b56/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/src/CognitoUser.js#L1143)

You can see they store the tokens to local storage for you.

To view the tokens from Google Chrome, go to developer tools -> Application. You should see a 'Storage' section on the left hand side. Open Local Storage, the tokens are saved under the URL of the application.

You should not need to access these token directly, the SDK will fetch and save the tokens as required when you call different methods.